# How to add a fade in/out method to the JS audio object

Tags: javascript, html, audio

so I'm tinkering with the new Audio object, and I wanna add a .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() methods to the object, so it'll be easy for me to invoke something like:

music_bgm.fadeOut();

... when the user mutes the audio, instead of having it abruptly stop.

I'm not exactly a connoisseur of JS, so please bear with me if I'm way off mark here:

1. Create the function `function fadeOut()`
2. Add a for loop or something which assumes the current volume is 100, and incrementally reduces it to 0 using `setTimeout()`

I'm confused all across the board, and reading about creating new objects and adding methods to existing objects in theory isn't helping...

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this js library: [Buzz](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/documentation/sound/) - it allows to do what you need. Just use it.